# No wireless with lubuntu 14.04 and iwconfig shows card twice

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, network-manager, 14.04, cisco

I just installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a Thinkpad T42 (with forcepae option). Everything is working fine but wifi. The applet shows only a few of the nearby networks. If my home network shows, it asks for the key, but then does nothing. Security is set to WPA as the card cannot handle WPA2. What bothers me is that iwconfig shows two identical wireless cards, one as `eth0` and one as `wifi0`.

iwconfig output is:

> wifi0   IEEE 802.11-DS  ESSID:""
>
> > ```
> >      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Invalid   
> >       Bit Rate:11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   Sensitivity=0/65535  
> >       Retry limit:16   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
> >       Power Management:off
> >       Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=-108 dBm  Noise level=-108 dBm
> >       Rx invalid nwid:10245  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
> >       Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:84223   Missed beacon:0
> > ```
>
> eth1      IEEE 802.11-DS  ESSID:""
>
> > ```
> >      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Invalid   
> >       Bit Rate:11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   Sensitivity=0/65535  
> >       Retry limit:16   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
> >       Power Management:off
> >       Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=-108 dBm  Noise level=-108 dBm
> >       Rx invalid nwid:10245  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
> >       Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:84223   Missed beacon:0
> > ```

output of lshw -C Network is

> *-network:0
>
> > ```
> >   Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
> >    Produkt: 82540EP Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Mobile)
> >    Hersteller: Intel Corporation
> >    Physische ID: 1
> >    Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:01.0
> >    Logischer Name: eth0
> >    Version: 03
> >    Seriennummer: 00:0d:60:79:16:16
> >    Größe: 100Mbit/s
> >    Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
> >    Breite: 32 bits
> >    Takt: 66MHz
> >    Fähigkeiten: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
> >    Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.2.102 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
> >    Ressourcen: irq:11 memory:c0220000-c023ffff memory:c0200000-c020ffff ioport:8400(Größe=64) memory:c0240000-c024ffff
> > ```
>
> *-network:1
>
> > ```
> >   Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
> >    Produkt: Cisco Aironet Wireless 802.11b
> >    Hersteller: Cisco Aironet Wireless Communications
> >    Physische ID: 2
> >    Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:02.0
> >    Logischer Name: wifi0
> >    Version: 00
> >    Seriennummer: 00:0e:9b:40:db:2c
> >    Breite: 32 bits
> >    Takt: 33MHz
> >    Fähigkeiten: pm vpd bus_master cap_list rom logical wireless ethernet physical
> >    Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=airo latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=4 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11-DS
> >    Ressourcen: irq:11 ioport:8000(Größe=256) memory:c0214000-c0217fff memory:c0400000-c07fffff memory:c0800000-c09fffff
> > ```

Note that the logical name here is `wifi0` while the network manager shows `eth1`. Interestingly, I can scan with `iwlist` on both of them and see, at least some, nearby networks. I remember that getting drivers for this card in XP was very painful, but it seems to be properly recognized here. Using `ifconfig`, however shows only errors and that is on `eth1`

So, any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: What does this tell us? sudo iwlist eth1 auth Thanks!

Comment: That gives `eth1 unknown authentication information`. Same on `wifi0`

Comment: My suspicion is that the old Aironet not only doesn't do WPA2 but, at least in Linux, doesn't do WPA at all. When you scan, does it report any WPA networks?

Comment: Yes, with `sudo iwlist eth1 scan` I see WPA and WPA2 networks.

Comment: It is not the encryption; even with no encryption, open network, it does not work.

Comment: Although, you might be correct anyway. `nm-tool` states that that the cards capabilities are `WEP`, if this is what you ment.

Comment: Exactly! You can't connect to WPA/WPA2 networks because the card/driver combination can't do it. The second interface was somewhat common in older cards and drivers, which the Aironet certainly is. As WEP is quite insecure, I suggest a newer device.

Comment: Ok, I'll probably test it with WEP, but of course not keep it like this. The T42 is not worth the trouble for a newer device, so I'll let it work via cable then. However, still strange that it does not work without encryption and the `eth1` and `wifi0` in parallel still puzzles me.

Comment: There are many USB wireless devices that can be bought for US$10-15. If you decide to do so, be sure to research Ubuntu compatibility carefully.

Comment: Good point. That's definitively an option. Little research also revealed that replacing the card is not too complicated. I'll evaluate which one is more convenient. At the moment it stays on cable.

Comment: If you decide to replace the card, please be aware of this: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card

Comment: @mikuszefski You can get T42 wifi cards (pulled from broken T42s) for about $5 on ebay. The Atheros abg card with open source madwifi driver works great (tested on Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian Wheezy).